# xmlimport pass parameter Is there a way to combine the two?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have the following code that reads an xml, how can I make the url dynamic according to the file to open

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
        "C:\Users\DIEGO\Downloads\NAD901023GRA_M6043818733.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")
```

and

```
strArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strArchivo = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strArchivo
```

Comment: "dynamic according to the file to open" is not very clear - where would the file path be coming from?  It's a string, so you can use any relevant value there...

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= strArchivo, ...`